# Plugin creation - how to add user rights?

Tags: user-roles, user-access

I wrote a little wordpress plugin and I want to grant only specific roles or users access to it. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here how register a role specifically for a plugin and add plugin specific capabilities to selected core roles

```
function my_plugin_install() {
   // add a new role for plugin with some capabilities
   add_role('my_plugin_role', 'My Plugin Role', array(
     'manage_my_plugin' => true, // plugin specific capability
     'read' => true // core capability
   ));
   // add plugin capabilities for some standard roles
   $roles = array('administrator', 'editor', 'author');
   $roles_obj = new WP_Roles();
   foreach ($roles as $role_name) {
      $roles_obj->add_cap($role_name, 'manage_my_plugin' ); 
   }
}


function my_plugin_unistall() {
    remove_role( 'my_plugin_role' );
    $roles = array('administrator', 'editor', 'author');
    $roles_obj = new WP_Roles();
    foreach ($roles as $role_name) {
      $roles_obj->remove_cap($role_name, 'manage_my_plugin' ); 
    }
}
```

In the plugin file put:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_install' );
register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_unistall');
```

To check in the current logged user has your plugin capabilities use :

```
if ( current_user_can('manage_my_plugin') ) {
  // do something
}
```

### Docs:

- [add role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role)
- [WP_Roles Class](http://phpdoc.wordpress.org/trunk/WordPress/User/WP_Roles.html)
- [remove role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_role)
- [register_activation_hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook)
- [register_uninstall_hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_uninstall_hook)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-user-permissions-and-your-plugin/

Comment: Thanks, this will come in handy but the problem is that custom plugins (like AllInOneSEO) are not displayed to authors in the backend. Is there a way to make them visible?